# How do you prevent a webView from claiming focus from a search field. Objc-C, Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, focus

I have an app that has a webView. It has a toolbar that contains a searchfield. This search field automatically searches while you type. (In this case it searches Wikipedia). However, if you type something that Wikipedia doesn't know about. Wikipedia will take you to the "Advanced Search" Page.

However, this page automatically steels focus from my search field. Thereby disrupting the user's typing. How do I make it so my webView NEVER steels focus? This is on Cocoa, not Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Check the webview delegate methods. You might have to add a [searchbar becomefirstresponder] in one of those.

Comment: Well that brings up another question I posted before that never got answered. How do you add a delegate method to webViews. I didn't see a webViewDelegate to place in the .h file. There is something like that on Cocoa-Touch, but not on Cocoa.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I should have read the last line that it is not cocoa touch. For cocoa, I saw this, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/WebUIDelegate. Anything useful in that?

Comment: Nope. Those are all informal methods. Although they do perform some useful tasks, they do not seem to have a delegate in the way Cocoa Touch does. Therefore, there is nothing to override here. This might be for Apple's own security on Safari or something similar.

Comment: Okay. I actually got the delegate method. Except that adding that line isn't really what I want. That makes it so any time my webView loads, it makes the search field the first-responder. That of course, is even more annoying than before.